# How to use SeekBar in RecyclerView's Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-seekbar

I'm getting some MP3 files from an API and showing them in the recyclerView by mediaPlayer and SeekBar. Everything works fine But there are 2 problems:

1. The mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener Doesn't work .
2. The Seekbar Doesn't work at all , it has no functionality , it doesn't move and the seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener doesn't
   work. I have used the Timer class and my TextView Which is supposed
   to show current time of the mediaPlayer works properly in timer ,
   but seekBar does not !

I have tried every possibility to fix the problem but I couldn't.

Here is my code for the ViewHolder :

```
        private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        private SeekBar seekBar;
        private TextView currentTime;
        private Timer timer;
        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        private SimpleDraweeView artistProfile;
        private SimpleDraweeView socialNetworkTypeImage;
        private TextView artistName;
        private TextView postReleaseDate;
        private TextView likes;
        private String urlMp3;
        private View playButtonContainer;
        private ImageView playButton;
        private ImageView pauseButton;
        private int mediaPlayerDuration;
        private Handler seekHandler = new Handler();

        TelegramVoiceViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            seekBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sb_news_feed_items_telegram_voice_seekbar);
            currentTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_news_feed_items_telegram_voice_time);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_news_feed_items_telegram_voice_progress_bar);
            artistProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sdv_news_feed_telegram_voice_artist_profile);
            socialNetworkTypeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sdv_news_feed_telegram_voice_social_type);
            artistName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_news_feed_items_telegram_voice_artist_name);
            postReleaseDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_telegram_voice_page_timer);
            likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_news_feed_items_telegram_voice_post_likes);
            playButtonContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_news_feed_items_telegram_voice_play_button);
            playButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_news_feed_items_telegram_voice_play_button_image);
            pauseButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_news_feed_items_telegram_voice_pause_button_image);


        }

        private void onBindViews(DataItem dataItem) {

            urlMp3 = dataItem.getAttachment().get(0).getFile();
            artistProfile.setImageURI(Uri.parse(dataItem.getUser().getAvatar()));
            socialNetworkTypeImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(TELEGRAM_ICON));
            socialNetworkTypeImage.setCropToPadding(true);
            socialNetworkTypeImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            postReleaseDate.setText(TimeAgo.getTimeAgo(Long.parseLong(dataItem.getDate())));
            likes.setText(dataItem.getLikes() + " People Liked This");
            artistName.setText(dataItem.getUser().getName());

        }

        private void setUpMediaPlayer() {

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            try {

                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(urlMp3));

                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mediaPlayer -> {

                    setUpMediaPlayerElements();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(new MainTimer(), 0, 1000);

                });

                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> {

                    pauseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mp.seekTo(0);

                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        private void setUpMediaPlayerElements() {


            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());

            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                    if (fromUser) {
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });

            playButtonContainer.setOnClickListener(view -> {

                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    pauseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {

                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

            });

        }

        private String formatDuration(long duration) {

            int seconds = (int) (duration / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds %= 60;
            return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d", minutes) + ":" + String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d", seconds);
        }

        private class MainTimer extends TimerTask {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(() -> {

                    seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

                    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener((mp, percent) -> seekBar.setSecondaryProgress((percent * mp.getDuration()) / 100));

                    currentTime.setText(formatDuration(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));

                });

            }
        }

    }
```

and then I call the onBindViews method in the onBindViewHolder :

```
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

       DataItem data = dataItems.get(i);

       if (data != null) {

                   ((TelegramVoiceViewHolder) viewHolder).onBindViews(data);
                   ((TelegramVoiceViewHolder) viewHolder).setUpMediaPlayer();

                   break;
}
```